# implicit convert from lambda to std::function inside variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to implement a template function which takes a lambda as argument.

```
#include <functional>

template<typename ... Result> using Fun = std::function<void(Result ...)>;
template<typename ... Result> void yield(Fun<Result ...>&& body) {};

template <typename T>
struct identity {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename ... Result> void yield2(typename identity<Fun<Result ...>>::type && body) {};

int main() {
    yield<char>(
        Fun<char>(
            [](char) -> void {} // 1. success
        )
    );

    yield2<char>(
        [](char) -> void {} // 2. success with identify
    );

    yield<char>(
        [](char) -> void {} // 3. fail, seems achievable
    );

    yield(
        [](char) -> void {} // 4. fail, impossible ?
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Why case 3 fails ? I already giving the template parameters to the template, so it should be able to deduce the function type and implicit convert the lambda to function

**EDIT:**

Compiler always reduce template parameters from function arguments, can we reverse it ?

```
    yield<char>(
        [](auto&& c) -> void {} // 5. is it possible ?
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a variadic template, and it starts trying to see "what else" it can deduce besides your explicit `char` argument.

If you had a single argument template like so:

```
template<typename Result> using Fun = std::function<void(Result)>;
template<typename Result> void yield(Fun<Result>&& body) {};
```

You'll notice that

```
yield<char>(
    [](char) -> void {} // 3. fail, seems achievable
);
```

Has no trouble at all because the entirety of `std::function` is deducible.

But as soon as we make a variadic template our compilers become unhappy:

```
template<class... Result> using Fun = std::function<void(Result...)>;
template<class... Result> void yield(Fun<Result...>&& body) {};
```

This is because, like it or not, the compiler is going to try to deduce more template arguments for `Fun<Result...>` given the **value** that was passed in ([temp.deduct.type]).

`yield2` sidesteps this issue because it places the resulting type into a **non-deduced** context, but since you explicitly specify the template arguments, it will use only those explicitly specified arguments (`char`) to deduce the type (#1 works for basically the same reason).

The best workaround I think is your `yield2` attempt, however you may also do something like this to prevent the value being passed from participating in type deduction:

```
auto fn = &yield<char>;
fn(
    [](char) -> void {}
);
```

Another workaround is to `static_cast` your call to `yield` to the proper type:
(Really I'm just reading through other possible workarounds under "The non-deduced contexts are:" for [temp.deduct.type])

```
using fn_type = void(*)(Fun<char>&&);

static_cast<fn_type>(&yield)(
    [](char) -> void {}
);
```

---

**Edit:** Finally, you could write some additional boilerplate templating to make the call look nicer (something approaching your #4). Bear in mind this is an incomplete impl made for example:

The goal of this templating is to detect the lambda's `operator()` function and extract its return type and arguments so that we can explicitly specify a `Fun` type when we call `yield` (extracting the return type is unnecessary since you're only ever using `void`):

First a helper struct that will allow us to detect an immutable lambda's return type and argument types:

```
template<class T>
struct Fun_Type;

template<class C, class Ret, class... Args>
struct Fun_Type<Ret(C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = Fun<Args...>;
};
```

Second, our helper function, `call_yield`, that passes on `Fun_Type<...>::type` to a call to `yield`:

```
template<class ImmutableLambda>
void call_yield(ImmutableLambda&& c)
{
    using Fun_t = typename Fun_Type<decltype(&ImmutableLambda::operator())>::type;
    yield(Fun_t{std::forward<ImmutableLambda>(c)});
}
```

And now we can call it simply:

```
int main() {
    call_yield(
        [](char) -> void {}
    );
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GvRGhVy9ShgIOS6S) (C++11)